# Adding/changing numbers in specific lines

Tags: text, notepad++

I have a big file with 250,000 lines and I want to change the numbers every 36 lines.
Example of my file:

```
 rankup_cost_increase_percentage: 0.0
    removepermission:
    - essentials.warps.B
    - essentials.warps.C
    - essentials.warps.D
    - essentials.warps.E
    - essentials.warps.F
    - essentials.warps.G
    - essentials.warps.H
    - essentials.warps.I
    - essentials.warps.J
    - essentials.warps.K
    - essentials.warps.L
    - essentials.warps.M
    - essentials.warps.N
    - essentials.warps.O
    - essentials.warps.P
    - essentials.warps.Q
    - essentials.warps.R
    - essentials.warps.S
    - essentials.warps.T
    - essentials.warps.U
    - essentials.warps.W
    - essentials.warps.X
    - essentials.warps.Y
    - essentials.warps.Z
    executecmds:
    - "[CONSOLE] crate give to %player% Legendary 1"
    - "[CONSOLE] crate give to %player% Multiplier 1"
    - "[player] warp A"
  P7437:
    nextprestige: P7438
    cost: 3.7185E13
    display: '&8[&9P7437&8]'
    rankup_cost_increase_percentage: 0.0
```

I want `rankup_cost_increase_percentage: 0.0` to increase by 5.0 everytime.
How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Is that a structure of your file? If those things are repeated over and over, you could use some regular expression for that. If I understood everything correctly. Column editor can work as well

Comment: You might be able to load the file into a spreadsheet. Use ":" as column separator. Filter for "rankup_cost_increase_percentage" in first column and calculate the increase in a third column, then copy third to second column using values. 
Notepad++ alone is not sufficient if you really need to *calculate* the increase (as in old new_value = old_value * 5.0 ).

Comment: You will need a text editor that supports very large files and scriptable macros like `EmEditor`. I could answer this question if it is OK with `EmEditor`.